# How to get canceled payments detail

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal classic API and fetching all PayPal transaction detail using following code.

```
$info =  'USER=api_username&PWD=api_password&SIGNATURE=api_sgnature&VERSION=94&METHOD=GetTransactionDetails&TRANSACTIONID='.$value;

$curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$str    =   $result;
parse_str($result, $result);

foreach($result as $key => $value){
        echo $key.' => '.$value."<BR>";
}
```

Following output, I am getting for created and canceled payments or transactions.

```
ADDRESSOWNER => PayPal
ADDRESSSTATUS => None
TIMESTAMP => 2015-06-26T05:10:54Z
CORRELATIONID => 4dad1aa370757
ACK => Failure
VERSION => 94
BUILD => 17103657
L_ERRORCODE0 => 10004
L_SHORTMESSAGE0 => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
L_LONGMESSAGE0 => The transaction id is not valid
L_SEVERITYCODE0 => Error
PENDINGREASON => None
REASONCODE => None
L_TAXABLE0 => true
```

As you can see from response that neither I am getting transaction id nor email of cancelled transaction so there is no way to recognize this transaction.

What can be the error or is there any alternative?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Of course if you call GetTransactionDetails without a transaction ID it will fail with exactly that error. Why are you expecting something different? Or put another way, why are you calling GetTransactionDetails in the first place, if you don't have a transaction to get the details of?

Comment: I have transaction id in case of transaction search but when i try to get details then i am not getting who has canceled payment and about which subscription payment has been canceled.

Comment: This error message says you have not provided a valid reference (transaction ID) for lookup. What ID are you passing? If you look up the payment in the UI, is the ID you are passing showing as the ID of a payment there?